# AJAX and CSS vs W3C (loading external content inside a div and <style>)

Tags: css, ajax

I'm having problems with the content loaded with AJAX inside a DIV.

I need custom CSS for the loaded content, but using `<style>` tag inside the div (or anywhere outside the `<head>`) does not respect the W3C standards.
Even more, in IE8 using `<style>` inside the div is not working as expected.

How can we solve this situation?

Comment: Please show some code and describe in more detail what the problem is, I don't understand yet

Comment: I have a div in "index.php" I load "somecontent.php" inside that div with AJAX, but somecontent has custom CSS styles... how can I add those styles without using < style > inside the body of somecontent.php?... and I'm not using IE :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have the AJAX response modify the the contents of the `<head>` tag and add a new `style` tag.  Your response would have two parts to it, the HTML and the CSS.  The CSS should be added to the document before the HTML to ensure it is used.

Check out this post for adding CSS to the head: [i prepend the css to the end of head tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629297/i-prepend-the-css-to-the-end-of-head-tag/629422#629422)

I'm assuming you have already been able to load something with AJAX into your page.  Just convert your response to a JSON response with two parts, the CSS and the HTML.  The [JSON Spec](http://json.org/) might help too.  You will need to escape any HTML or CSS that you send as a response.

Comment: I'm not using JQuery because I want to mantain the lowest filesize (and JQuery is 70KB).<br>
Do you know an example without JQuery? I think the same solution can be used for loading < script > tags with AJAX inside a div

Comment: jquery is only 26KB minified. even if you don't use jQuery (which you should), you can still do this with AJAX, but you have to make it up yorself or use something like this: http://www.ajaxtoolbox.com/request/examples.php